# How to show Office addin taskpane icon default in message surface?

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin

Latest office add-in icons showing in the the overflow menu in the outlook explorer view. But I want to show this in default without setting any mail settings. ( check the attach image, I want show task bar button shows in the message surface area )

Do I need to add any changes in manifest file ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently do not support pinning on an email surface from the Manifest. It can only be done through the settings option inside of Outlook Web app and is specific to the client. Add-ins are also pinned on the email surface by default when installing from the marketplace from Outlook Web App (unless the user specifically unpins it)

Currently the feature you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins